# How I can create database with rails? Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, docker, ruby-on-rails-7

first of all I'm using windows 11 with WSL2 ubuntu 20.04.
I'm build an image with docker where are install ruby and postgresql.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres:14.1-bullseye'
    volumes:
      - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust

  redis:
    image: 'redis:6.2.6-bullseye'
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/data'

  web:
    depends_on:
      - 'db'
      - 'redis'
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    ports:
      - '3002:3000'
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=db

volumes:
  redis:
  postgres:
```

### `ruby 3.1.2-bullseye`

Everything works fine, I created a new project with `rails new project-name --api --database=postgresql -T` and a `docker compose build` works fine.
After that I want to create a database with `docker compose run web rails db:create` and now problem appears.

I'm getting this error:

```
We could not find your database: postgres. Which can be found in the database configuration file located at config/database.yml.

To resolve this issue:

- Did you create the database for this app, or delete it? You may need to create your database.
- Has the database name changed? Check your database.yml config has the correct database name.

To create your database, run:

        bin/rails db:create
Couldn't create 'greenhouse_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: We could not find your database: postgres. Which can be found in the database configuration file located at config/database.yml.

To resolve this issue:

- Did you create the database for this app, or delete it? You may need to create your database.
- Has the database name changed? Check your database.yml config has the correct database name.

To create your database, run:

        bin/rails db:create


Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I don't know what is going on, for help and sign what I'm doing wrong thansk in advance.

*UPDATE*
`database.yml`

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_HOST") { "db" } %>
  port: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_PORT") { 5432 } %>
  username: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_USERNAME") { "postgres" } %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_PASSWORD") { "password" } %

development:
  <<: *default
  database: greenhouse_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: greenhouse_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: greenhouse_production
  username: greenhouse
  password: <%= ENV["GREENHOUSE_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>
```

Comment: What is in that `database.yml` file?  How do you configure it to point at the `db` container?

Comment: @DavidMaze just updated question with database.yml. I'd appreciate it if you'd take a look

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I did not solve this problem directly. To generally solve this problem I downloaded a sample rails 7 docker repository and changed only API under my own.
Here is the link to the repository I used https://github.com/ryanwi/rails7-on-docker

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely recall there being some wonkiness around loading env vars in db config files. You can initialize rails without a DB connection while docker is building if you use the [nulldb adapter](https://github.com/nulldb/nulldb):

```rb
# database.build.yml 
build:
  adapter: nulldb
```

```rb
FROM somebase as build
...
RUN cp ./config/database.build.yml ./config/database.yml 
  && RAILS_ENV=build bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would prefer not to install additional gems that affect the database

Comment: You can follow the instructions in the Docker docs (https://docs.docker.com/samples/rails/) if you're learning, but your yaml file referenced 'production' so I gave you a suggestion appropriate to a professional environment where you're building an image with precompiled assets for CI. You likely need to update your `docker-compose` file to ensure you're setting the env vars your container needs (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment) and review examples in `docker/awesome-compose` (https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/).

Answer (score 0):

I just came accross the same problem. I have the same system windows 11 wsl Ubuntu. And it turned out, it was just because i didn't start the postgresql server.

So in the terminal i did go to this place :

```
cd /var/lib/postgresql
```

Then :

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

Then go back to your folder (with your rails app) and do `rake db:create`
again

I hope it helps others who came accross the same issue.